# Variable being treated as scalar and not list

Tags: python, robotframework

I'm currently following a course where the following is used

```
*** Settings ***

*** Variables ***
${MY_VARIABLE} =    Hello There    Item 2      Value 3

*** Test Cases ***
Variable demonstration
    Log    ${MY_VARIABLE}
    Log    ${MY_VARIABLE}[0]
    Log    ${MY_VARIABLE}[1]
    Log    ${MY_VARIABLE}[2]

Var Demo 2
    ${my_list_var} =    set variable    Hello There    Item 2    Value 3
    Log    ${my_list_var}[0]
    Log    ${my_list_var}[1]
    Log    ${my_list_var}[2]
```

The expected result, from the video should be Hello There, Item 2 and Value 3 in both cases.
Logging {MY_VARIABLE} returns Hello There Item 2 Value 3, when ['Hello There', 'Item 2', 'Value 3'] should be expected. ${MY_VARIABLE}[0] is logged as 'H', ${MY_VARIABLE}[1] as 'e' and ${MY_VARIABLE}[2] as 'l'.

I'm unsure if this in a syntax issue(though I've copied the video) or if it has to do with a change in syntax in the robot framework, as the video still uses @ rather than $ for list variables.

It seems to me that ${MY_VARIABLE} is treating the variable as a string, and like a character array, accessing the char at [0],[1] and [2] respectively. ${my_list_var} logs accurately with 'Hello There', 'Item 2' and 'Value 3' respectively. How do I make ${MY_VARIABLE} into a list variable?

Comment: is this python?

Comment: @TalhaTayyab It's robot framework, which is python based. Not sure if how list variables are treated is inherited in any way/

Answer (score 2):

When you define list variable in `*** Variables ***` section you must use `@` operator. Otherwise it will be considered as space separated string. Something like `' '.join(*args)`.

```
*** Variables ***
@{MY_VARIABLE} =    Hello There    Item 2      Value 3
```

When you define list variable with [Set Variable](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Variable) you can use both `$` and `@` operators and pass several arguments. It will work fine. However it is recommended to create list with [Create List](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Create%20List) keyword like this:

```
@{my_list_var} =    Create List    Hello There    Item 2    Value 3
```

or this:

```
${my_list_var} =    Create List    Hello There    Item 2    Value 3
```

**UPD:**
Code example:

```
*** Variables ***
@{MY_VARIABLE} =    Hello There    Item 2      Value 3

*** Test Cases ***
Variable demonstration
    Log To Console    ${MY_VARIABLE}
    Log To Console    ${MY_VARIABLE}[0]
    Log To Console    ${MY_VARIABLE}[1]
    Log To Console    ${MY_VARIABLE}[2]

Var Demo 2
    ${my_list_var} =    Create List    Hello There    Item 2    Value 3
    Log To Console    ${my_list_var}
    Log To Console    ${my_list_var}[0]
    Log To Console    ${my_list_var}[1]
    Log To Console    ${my_list_var}[2]
```

Output:

```
==============================================================================
Variable demonstration    .['Hello There', 'Item 2', 'Value 3']
.Hello There
.Item 2
.Value 3
Variable demonstration                                                | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Var Demo 2    .['Hello There', 'Item 2', 'Value 3']
.Hello There
.Item 2
.Value 3
Var Demo 2                                                            | PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! Was confused because the docs talked about using @ when using create list, while the video said to use $ instead.